# "Error: data should be 2 dimensional "while trying solr_facet

Tags: r, solr, shiny, faceted-search, rsolr

when i am using a solr_facet search on my data , i get a reactive data but when i try to render it onto a table and view the fetched data i get the **error : data must be 2 dimensional** . Could anyone help with this ?
I can see the facet values and the respective counts in my console but not when i try to run the App.
Sample Code :

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library("solr")
library(DT)

data_input <- eventReactive(input$gobutton,{url=*****
solr_facet(q=input$obj,fl='*',facet.field = 'value',rows=1000,base = url)})

output$view <- renderDataTable({
    head(datasetInput(), n = 100)
  })
```

Comment: please include any packages used and make your example complete, so that it generates the error message you are asking about

Comment: i have added the packages used to the code

Comment: I get `Error: unexpected '^' in "data_input <- eventReactive(input$gobutton,{url=**"`, could you add a reproducible and safe url?